# Redefine Object.defineProperty in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, setter

I would like to learn if it is possible to redefine the "definePropery" function of the Object(.prototype) in a subclass(.prototype) so that the setter not only sets the value of the property but also eg executes an additional method.

I have tried something like that:

```
Myclass.prototype.defineProperty = function (obj, prop, meth) {
    Object.defineProperty.call(this, obj, prop, {
        get: function () {
            return obj[prop]
        },
        set: function () {
            obj[prop] = n;
            alert("dev")
        }
    })
}
```

But id does not work

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Define "does not work". Does it not work as expected, not at all, throw an error…

Comment: What precisely doesn't _wort_ about it? What happens instead of what you expect? And how are you invoking this code?

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be confused about how `Object.defineProperty` works. You only *ever* call `defineProperty` on `Object`, and you pass in the object you want to define a property of.  So you don't need this magic, because `defineProperty` does not exist on instances of your class at all.

```
var obj = {a:123};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo');
// works fine!

obj.defineProperty('foo');
// TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'defineProperty'
```

But that means you can add that in, no problem:

```
Myclass.prototype.defineProperty = function (obj, prop, meth) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
        get: function () {
            return obj[prop]
        },
        set: function (n) {
            obj[prop] = n;
            alert("dev")
        }
    })
}
```

Note this line:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
```

We pass in the object we want the property on (`this`), and the name of the property (`prop`).  Then the setter/getter object.  No need to override anything at all.  You are simple providing a method that allow an object to declare it's own properties.

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TeZ82/

Comment: It seems that I did miss a point about the Object.defineProperty method. What I really thought is that defineProperty is called behind the scenes every time the new property is defined for the objects. If so what I meant to do is to reopen "Object" class and redefine the method.

Comment: `defineProperty` is _not_ called when you create a property.  You call `Object.defineProperty` to create a property of an object with custom behavior.  You can get callbacks with [Harmony Proxies](http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/proxies/) but I believe support for them is somewhat uncommon at the moment.